# handle external javascript script loaded event before it's executed

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have an `html` page and a `script` which I want to handle in specific way: after it's loaded but before it's executed. Basically I want to pre-load script but execute when certain criteria met. Script doesn't depend on other scripts so I make it non-blocking (`async`):

```
<script onload='onScripLoad()' scr='...' async></script>
```

All I want is something similar to `onload` but which is executed before the downloaded script. Is it possible?

The issue here is that I'm able to pre-load the script but unable to sync with the required event in my app lifecycle. The `onScripLoad` is executed `after` script has been loaded `AND` `after` it has been executed. What I need is to have control when script is executed (postpone execution).

Adding more details I want to pre-load the script and execute it when certain element is available in the `body` but I cannot put the script right after that element because in this case it gets queued with a few other resources which are being downloaded in the `head`. Thus I want to place my script in the `head`, make it `async` and once it's downloaded execute only when specific element is available (or event create that element before executing). I cannot make it not async because it's a script which I have no control and wouldn't like my whole page depend on it.

Comment: Can't you put the code in the external script in a function and then only call that function once both conditions are true?

Comment: Can't you just house the logic in the external script in a function, which gets loaded early, and then call that function from a secondary script when a certain condition is true?

Comment: That is how I would do it if I have control over the external script. Unfortunately it's a 3d party library and it has certain javascript which is executed right after begin downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

You could just load the external script in the head section, wrap the logic inside a function, and then call that function inside a condition at a later point:

**externalscript.js:**

```
function externalFunction(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

**Index:**

```
<head>
  <script src='externalscript.js' async></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  var body_data = 'test';
  if (timing-driven-condition) {
    externalFunction(body_data);
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

The function `externalFunction` would be loaded first, but wouldn't be used until it was called within the condition, giving you control over when it executes.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: *"The function externalFunction would be loaded immediately"* - Even with the `async` attribute?

Comment: I meant it would be loaded first :P

Comment: That is how I would do it if I have control over the external script. Unfortunately it's a 3d party library and it has certain javascript which is executed right after begin downloaded.